# What search term(s) should I use when looking for a pronunciation guide of ancient kanji?

Tags: kanji, readings, furigana, old-japanese

I've recently developed interest in reading/studying the 古事記{こじき}, and simply searching for the term「古事記」gives plenty of results with the original text. However, I am having trouble finding any results with ふりがな. I've tried searching using the following terms suggested by Google:

> 古事記 読み方, 古事記 漢字 読み方

These only seem to produce results for interpretations of the text and not the readings of each character.

> 古事記 読みやすい

This one seems to produce modern reproductions of the ancient text meant for casual reading.

> 古事記 ふりがな

Nothing meaningful came out of this one either. I know that somewhere there's an edition with the ふりがな included but I just have no clue how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 古事記　書き下し is the search term you're looking for.

The 古事記 is written in Classical Chinese（漢文）so there wouldn't be any furigana for that.

**However,** Classical Chinese can be re-written as a 書き下し文 which has kana.

There is an example here:
http://www.linkclub.or.jp/~pip/ututu/kami/furukotobumi/jyo1.html

Comment: Thank you, this immediately gave me [this link](http://www004.upp.so-net.ne.jp/dassai1/kojiki_kami/frame/kojiki_kami_frame.htm) which is exactly what I was looking for.